# sort chars without replacing

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

Trying to sort chars in string in C. Sort their ASCII codes. I tried bubble sort and selection sort methods.

```
char stroka[]="This programmator";
int n=17,tmp;

for (int i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
    for (int j=n-2;j>=0;j--)
        if(stroka[j]>stroka[j+1])
        {
            tmp=stroka[j];
            stroka[j]=stroka[j+1];
            stroka[j+1]=tmp;
        }
printf("%s",stroka);
```

Everything's great with this allocation:

```
char stroka[]="This programmator";
```

But it fails on this

```
char *stroka="This programmator";
```

because this algorithms edit protected array.
I can make another heap value like

```
char *stroka_new= malloc(17);
```

and write sorted array there. It's not protected.
How to make it sorted in new value? Maybe someone know sort algorithm without replacing values?

Comment: recommend use [`qsort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/). if you can't then  you can use [`strdup`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) - assuming your sort logic is ok

Comment: There's no need for any special trick to get a sorted result from a non-modifiable input. Just copy it and sort the copy.

Comment: It is possible to sort by using a pointer(or index) instead of the actual element If the size of the element is large.

Comment: You want someone to sort values without moving them?  Can you clean your room without moving anything too?

Comment: should be `char *stroka_new= malloc(17+1);`

Answer (score 3):

One way is to [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/strdup.html) the original string and sort the result (not forgetting to `free()` it at the end)?

Answer (score 0):

**how to sort using the index.**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    const char *stroka="This programmator";
    int n=17;
    unsigned char index[n]; //or malloc 
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
        index[i]=i;
    for (int i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
        for (int j=n-2;j>=0;j--)
            if(stroka[index[j]]>stroka[index[j+1]]){
                unsigned char tmp;
                tmp=index[j];
                index[j]=index[j+1];
                index[j+1]=tmp;
            }
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i)// Taaghimmooprrrst
        putchar(stroka[index[i]]);//printf("%s",stroka);
    return 0;
}
```